# Path Parameter Regex

Tags: regex, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I have been trying to define a role for a specific API path in Spring Boot for HttpSecurity.
My path is basically like below:

> /v3/files/{uuid}?subject=SHARED_WITH_LINK

**uuid** --> is not static and something like that ***ACC-1a433a56-d5cf-4185-b55e-7ac75d530b79***

There may be extra path parameter like:

1. /v3/files/{uuid}?subject=SHARED_WITH_LINK
2. /v3/files/{uuid}?size=100&subject=SHARED_WITH_LINK
3. /v3/files/{uuid}?subject=SHARED_WITH_LINK&sortBy=name&size=100

To prevent unauthorized access to API, I have be to careful about regex. There must be **"/v3/files/"** exactly in regex. The **"{uuid}"** part can contains **alphanumeric** characters and the **'-'** character.
The remaining part of the path has to contain **"subject=SHARED_WITH_LINK"**

I could not build regex for this path format, it is a bit complex for me, and as I said I have a concern for unauthorized access.

Could you help me with building regex, please?

As an example, I have created the following regex (does not cover all the requirements mentioned above):

```
^/v3/files/[\w\-]*(\?)?$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something like the following:

```
^/v3/files/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\?(?:\w+=\w+&)*subject=SHARED_WITH_LINK(?:&\w+=\w+)*$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jKOCmZ/3)**.

**Notes:**

- Used `[A-Za-z0-9\-]` instead of `[\w-]` to be more restrictive (i.e., reject underscore and Unicode<sup>*</sup> alphanumeric).

  - Used the `+` quantifier instead of `*` for the UUID chars to avoid matching zero-length UUIDs. You might want to use a higher minimum length (i.e., `{n,}`) or if your UUID format is always the same (most likely the case), you should be more explicit and only match that specific format by using `ACC-[a-z0-9]{8}-(?:[a-z0-9]{4}-){3}[a-z0-9]{12}` instead.
- Used `\w+=\w+` to match a single parameter. You might want to replace `\w` with a character class that contains whatever character you want the parameter name/value to support.
- Even though the hyphen character doesn't need to be escaped when it's at the end of a character class, I prefer to explicitly escape it, especially when security is a concern. This ensures that the pattern doesn't break (or worse, accept unwanted characters) when more chars are appended.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Unicode support is likely disabled by default, but just to be safe.</sub>